# How to detect if expansion takes place while evaluating a \pgfmathparse-expression/if inside a \pgfmathparse-expression?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I intend to write a macro which behaves differently depending on whether used within a `\pgfmathparse`-expression or used outside a `\pgfmathparse`-expression.

For example a commend `\MyNicePi` which expands to the sequence `pi` within a `\pgfmathparse`-expressions **not nested between `"`...`"`** and to the control-word-token `\textpi` otherwise.

(The sequence `pi` is a recognized function inside `\pgfmathparse`-expressions.
When loading the package textgreek, then`\textpi` in horizontal and vertical modes delivers the symbol π.
`"` is the quote-operator in `\pgfmathparse`-expressions, i.e., things in quotes are expanded but not evaluated by `\pgfmathparse`.)

So the questions are:

Does the mathematical engine of PGF bring along a test or a switch for finding out if currently evaluation of a `\pgfmathparse`-expression is taking place?

If not:

- What is the best way to implement such a test oneself?
- What criteria can be used for determining whether currently evaluation of a `\pgfmathparse`-expression is taking place?

Something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\MyNicePi{%
  % A test for checking if pgfmathparse-evaluation takes place and either
  % pi or \textpi
}%

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\MyNicePi{} is approximately
\pgfmathparse{\MyNicePi}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}\,.

\end{document}
```

delivering the same as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\textpi{} is approximately
\pgfmathparse{pi}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}\,.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can check whether `\pgfmath@parse@next` is defined.  `\pgfmathparse` works inside a group and one of the first things it does is to define `\pgfmath@parse@next`, so it should be reliable in both cases.  With your example `\ifdefined\pgfmath@parse@next` seems to work.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `\ifdefined\pgfmath@parse@next` doses not take PGF's `"`-operator into account. I.e., with `\makeatletter\newcommand\MyNicePi{\ifdefined\pgfmath@parse@next\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{pi}{\textpi}}\makeatother` the expression `\pgfmathparse{"\MyNicePi"}\pgfmathresult` yields `pi` instead of `\textpi`.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that one (rather important :) requirement. Indeed `\pgfmath@parse@next` or egreg's method answers only “am I in `\pgfmathparse`?”. It's a lot trickier, as `\pgfmathparse` pre-expands its argument, so when it knows it's inside quotes, `\MyNicePi` has long been expanded.  I can hack something, but it won't be pretty

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, but don't spend time on that. 1) I can do the hack myself, I just didn't know if something was available already and I wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel. ;-)  2) I posted  a feature-request to the developers of TikZ/pgf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no particular way to recognize whether TeX is in the middle of performing `\pgfmathparse`, but it's not difficult to add a test, exploiting the fact that the definition of `\pgfmathparse` begins with `\begingroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifudparse
\patchcmd{\pgfmathparse}
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\udparsetrue}
  {}{}

\newcommand\MyNicePi{\ifudparse pi\else\textpi\fi}

\begin{document}

\MyNicePi{} is approximately
\pgfmathparse{\MyNicePi}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}\,.

\MyNicePi{} is approximately half of
\pgfmathsetmacro\foo{2*\MyNicePi}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\foo}\,.

\end{document}
```

The example shows that also `\pgfmathsetmacro` works (because it calls `\pgfmathparse` internally).

[image]

Also Phelype Oleinik's idea to test for `\pgfmath@parse@next` is good, but has the defect of depending on the particular name. Instead, `\begingroup` *has* to be performed by `\pgfmathparse`. Of course, if the maintainers decide to change the top level definition and to hide `\begingroup` in another macro, we're doomed.

I think this should be a feature request to the developers of Ti*k*Z/PGF.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As the if-switch is set to true by `\pgfmathparse` no matter what will parsed, PGF's quote-operator `"` is not taken into account. I.e., `\pgfmathparse{"\MyNicePi"}` yields `pi` instead of `\textpi`. I will send a feature request.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Sorry, but one should delve deep in the parser, I'm afraid. Perhaps there's a way to do `\udparsefalse` there, but there's full expansion lurking around…